# Record First Contentful Paint(FCP) on amp pages

Tags: javascript, performance, browser, pagespeed, observers

We know we can capture FCP with PerformanceObserver Apis like below:-

```
const observer = new PerformanceObserver((list) => {
    for (const entry of list.getEntries()) {
        if (entry && entry.entryType === "paint" && entry.name === "first-contentful-paint") {            
            //Send events to server apis here.
        }
    }
});
```

Start observing the entry types you care about. Below:-

```
observer.observe({ entryTypes: ['paint'] });
```

But I am not able to find, How to capture it in AMP pages. Can you please help me out?